# While running script getting error 'Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.' in selenium using ecllipse

Tags: selenium

Trying to run the *selenium* script using *eclipse* but getting an error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Tried by by deleting process in Task Manager, even though getting same issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You tried killing what process and why? What have you tried? How does the selenium communicate to the browser? (share your config / code please)

Comment: Chrome browser has been made end process in Task Manager. End process made because chrome browser running by ground to check that.

Comment: @Test(description = "Step 1: Open the browser, Enter the  URL", priority = 1)
 public void Step01_NavigeteToURL() throws Exception {

  // Navigates to  application URL
  homePage = HomePage.navigateToHomePage(driver, baseUrl);

  log.info("Successfully navigated to  Home page\n");
  Reporter.log("<p>Successfully navigated to  Home page");

 }